# How do I insert a section break in a RTF file but inherit the page layout etc from the previous section

Tags: ms-word, rtf, sections

My application generates a RTF file for the user to insert into their existing MS Word document. The RTF file inserts a continuous section break, sets the new section to two columns, outputs some text and then inserts another continuous section break which switches back to the original (one?) column style. The code for this is below and it works OK in MS Word to switch into two columns and switch back to the original layout.

My problem is that the document into which this is going to be inserted uses A4 paper, not US letter and has very large left, right, top and bottom margins - between 5 or 6 cm wide, but when my file is inserted, the two column section defaults back to US letter paper and the default narrow margins.

So my question is...

**What tag or control word do I need to use in my RTF file to tell it to continue using whatever page size and margins were in force before the section break (and return to them afterwards)?**

The RTF Pocket Guide [here](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/rtf-pocket-guide/9781449302047/ch01.html) seems to suggest that after a section break I should re-define all the page and paragraph formats but as I don't know where the user will insert my RTF file, I don't know what page size, margins and paragraph formatting is in force at that point. It also says that by **not** using the control word *\sectd* after a section break the new section will not reset to default but inherit attributes from the previous section. However this does not appear to happen with my file.

Here is the RTF that works to produce a 2 column section.

```
{\rtf1\ansi {\fonttbl{\f0\fcharset0 Times New Roman}}
{\f0\fs18\expnd0\expndtw0

{\pard Line of text in the original section with just one column \par}

\sect
\sbknone
\cols2  

 {
Line 1  text in a new, two column, section \par 
line 2  text in a new, two column, section \par 
line 3  text in a new, two column, section \par 
line 4  text in a new, two column, section \par 
line 5  text in a new, two column, section \par 
line 6  text in a new, two column, section \par 
 etc.
line 200  text in a new, two column, section \par 
line 201  text in a new, two column, section \par 
line 202  text in a new, two column, section \par 
}

\par 
\sect 
\sbknone

 {\pard Line of text in another section, back in the original one column format again \par}

}
}
```

To help visitors to this post that know even less RTF than I do, here is the meaning of the tags I've used.

- \rtf1 - tells the reader that its an RTF file conforming to spec 1
  (even though there is no spec 0 or 2!)
- {\rtf1\ansi {\fonttbl{\f0\fcharset0 Times New Roman}} - defines the
  font table    and which font to use
- \pard - resets the paragraph style to the defaults so we don't carry over any undesired formatting
- \par - indicates the end of a paragraph (\pard and \par often go together)
- \sect - starts a new section in the document
- \sbknone - indicates no page break before section, ie a 'continuous' section break
- \cols2 - says this section should contain 2 columns
- { and } act as block tags, like in C++, so the {} around the text between \cols2 and \par indicate that only that text is is two columns

*BTW I did try using a table and calculating where to put each item to get snaking columns instead of using real newspaper style columns like this but whilst that worked fine it became complicated when the table split across page boundaries so using \cols seemed simpler as that takes into account page breaks.*